# Why is the custom font not being used? Xamarin.Forms.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am working with custom fonts right now and currently a font named: "Yellowtail-Regular.tff". I created a map called `Fonts` in my iOS folder and I added the tff file in there. After that I went to my Info.plist and created a `Fonts provided by application` and in there I created a new string called `Fonts/Yellowtail-Regular.ttf`.

When I now try to use it like this:

```
<Label FontFamily = "Yellowtail" Text = "Testing my label" />
```

The standard font (Helvetica Neue) still remains. I also tried with:

```
<Label FontFamily = "Yellowtail-Regular" Text = "Testing my label" />
```

But with the same outcome.

Am I missing a step or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/labels/change_the_font/

Comment: I did not find Yellowtail-Regular in ios fonts, https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/fonts/enumerate_fonts/

Comment: Ah ok so if it isnt in the ios-fonts there is no way of adding it?

Comment: Try alter your file fonts for "Always copy"

Comment: Where do I find this? If i right click on the font I see build action, quick properties etc, is that option in there somewhere?

Comment: Visual Studio:
you can click right in file option Properties -> Copy to output Directory -> "Always copy".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using `Yellowtail-Regular.ttf` from http://www.1001freefonts.com/yellowtail.font, then that font name under `iOS` would be just `Yellowtail`.

Each platform has different naming conventions, so using `Device.OnPlatform` might look something like:

```
public Label()
{
  FontFamily = Device.OnPlatform("Yellowtail", "Yellowtail-Regular", "/Assets/Yellowtail-Regular.ttf#Yellowtail-Regular");      
}
```

**To confirm your iOS font family name, on `macOS` open your `.ttf` using `Font Book` and the name that `macOS`/`iOS` will use is the one in the title bar of the app.**

Comment: Solid advice, the opening the font with `Font Book`. I couldn't figure out the name! :P

Answer (score 7):

Some times font book will display the name with spaces.

In my case:
Font name is : `SFProDisplay-Ultralight`. But the font book shown the 
name as "SF Pro Display Ultralight". Due to this custom font is not working in iOS.

So you can use the below code to find the correct font name and apply it in the iOS.
Add this code in the AppDelegate launch method. Then you can find the list of viable font names in the Application output.

```
foreach (var family in UIFont.FamilyNames)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{family}");

    foreach (var names in UIFont.FontNamesForFamilyName(family))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{names}");
    }
}
```

After that you can use xaml to refer the font.

```
<OnPlatform x:Key="SFProDisplayUltraLight" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
    <On Platform="iOS" Value="SFProDisplay-Ultralight" />
    <On Platform="Android" Value="SF-Pro-Display-Ultralight.otf#SF Pro Display Ultralight" />
</OnPlatform>
```

Then Apply it for the control.

```
<Lable Text="Welcome" FontFamily="{StaticResource SFProDisplayUltraLight}"/>
```

Comment: This should be in the documentation. All the documentation I've read is vague or only has the name of a single font and only this correctly describes how to get the correct font names.