# Cannot use custom font on Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, truetype

I've been trying to use a custom font on Xamarin iOS but it simply does not work. This is my info.plist:

```
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>BebasNeue-Regular.ttf</string>
</array>
```

I also set the build action of the .ttf file to BundleResource and "always copy" as shown on several tutorials I already read. If I change the build action to Compile (as I found on other tutorials), it will simply not build.

EDIT: This is how it's being used

```
     <Label Text="Hello Forms with XAML">
<Label.FontFamily>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="BebasNeue-Regular" />
            <On Platform="Android" Value="BebasNeue-Regular.ttf#BebasNeue-Regular" />
    </OnPlatform>
</Label.FontFamily>
```

Comment: `but it simply does not work`... What is the problem that you are exactly having?

Comment: That it won't apply the font i'm trying to use.

Comment: It was simply added to the Resources folder on iOS project.

Comment: The only code needed (apparenlty) to be able to use the custom font is the one on info.plist. If you want me to add the code where I actually use it, I will.

Comment: @SushiHangover already edited to add usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the font in the macOS `Font Book` app and review the actual name:

```
PostScript name BebasNeueRegular
      Full name Bebas Neue Regular
```

So, in your code:

```
<On Platform="iOS" Value="Bebas Neue Regular" />
```

Re: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41567423/4984832

Re: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48191854/4984832

Re: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36942128/4984832

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the issue. I already went through every file name related to this and even retried adding the whole thing but does not seem to fix the problem. Edit: already read the posts you attached, thanks by the way.

Comment: I changed the name,  changed back to the "real" name and then rebuilt and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Lifesaver. Thanks! In my case name was the cause of error