# I can't get my custom fonts to work with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created this resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="CustomFrameApp.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Key="NewFont">
                <On Platform="iOS" Value="Camber_Medium_Regular" />
            </OnPlatform>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources> </Application>
```

added to info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Camber_Medium_Regular.otf</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and used in my XAML

```
<Label FontSize="12px" Text="ABCD" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontFamily="{StaticResource NewFont}" />
```

But the fonts are still not being used

I added them as bundle resource as suggested and they are in the resource file of iOS

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: *Assuming* your font name value is incorrect: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011220/cannot-use-custom-font-on-xamarin-ios/50011386#50011386

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Fonts in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts), please confirm three things:

1. If you have added font file tat called Camber_Medium_Regular.ttf in Resource file , and **Build Action:BundleResource**

2.Update the Info.plist, like this:

```
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>Camber_Medium_Regular.ttf</string>
</array>
```

3.Refer to it by name

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                <On Platform="iOS" Value="Camber_Medium_Regular" />
                <On Platform="Android" Value="Lobster-Regular.ttf#Lobster-Regular" />
                <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Fonts/Lobster-Regular.ttf#Lobster" />
            </OnPlatform>
```