# Custom Fonts are not working in Xamarin.IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I've added different custom fonts to my Xamarin application. It works fine on Android. However, I have a problem with iOS.

I am using the font that is named DancingScriptMedium and I added to the Resources file in the iOS layer of my project. I configured to properties as

[properties of the font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMVgt.png)

and I added it to Info.plist as shown inside of   tag.

```
  <key>UIAppFonts</key>
  <array> 
    <string>DancingScriptMedium.ttf</string> 
  </array>
```

In addition to these, I've added to App.xaml to the font as shown below.

```
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Key="DancingScript">
        <On Platform="Android" Value="Fonts/DancingScriptMedium.ttf#DancingScript" />
        <On Platform="iOS" Value="DancingScriptMedium"/>
    </OnPlatform>
```

And I use it this font in the Xaml page as shown.

```
 <Label Text="Hello World" FontFamily="{StaticResource DancingScript}" FontSize="Large"/>
```

Why it is not working? Where am I wrong?

Comment: I assuming the name for your font is incorrect (Quick font name check, open the font in macOS's "Font Book" and look at the name of the font in the title bar) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011220/cannot-use-custom-font-on-xamarin-ios/50011386#50011386

Comment: Try this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/using-custom-fonts-in-xamarinforms-for-ios-app

Comment: Is it necessary that the font is located in the Mac Font Book?

Comment: Okey, I got it. Thanks for your answers.